# Ввод целых чисел с консоли

Tags: c++

Как стандартными средствами проверить ввод целого числа с консоли?
Я хочу чтобы программа сообщала об ошибке, если будет введено примерно следующее:

- 123.3
- 1223aaw
- 123 122

Т.е. разрешается вводить только положительные и отрицательные целые.

Сам пробовал так:

```
while (!(cin >> k)) {
   if (cin.fail()) cout << "error" << endl;
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно считывать данные, а затем их отправлять специальный метод, который будет искать в переменной недопустимые символы.

Для поиска недопустимых символов хорошо подойдут регулярные выражения.

Если есть недопустимые символы, то возвращай `true`, а если нет то `false`,а  в вызывающем коде уже можешь сгенерировать исключение через `throw`.

Нашел еще вот такое решение:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  

int main()  
{  
  int length; 
  int width;  

  cout << "Enter the length: "; 
  cin >> length; // input the length 

  cout << "Enter the width: "; 
  cin >> width;  // input the width  

  cout << "The area is ";  
  cout << length * width;

  return 0;  
}
```

По идее если не удасться преобразовать строку в int, то вылетит ошибка.

Comment: Так конечно можно, но неужели для такой стандартной вещи нет библиотечного решения???

Comment: @dimotim, обновил.

Comment: Что-то не видно строки-то.